# Unable to extract string between double quotes using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net, string

I am trying to extract those substrings that are enclosed in double quotes using regular expression:

```
"\w[\w\s\t]*"
```

on string:

> "@test" skip **"2 3"** skip **"TEST"** skip **"te st"** skip "@#"

Bolded substrings are successfully extracted. But those with special characters are not extracted. Please help me solve this. I am not so pro in making regular expressions.

Comment: Hint: `\w` accepts letters, digits and underscores only.

Comment: You can use [^"] (i.e. "not quotes") as the character class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex should work

```
"(.+?)"
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ7fY4/1)

It uses the concept of [Group capture](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)

Answer (score 2):

You can also match a substring containing escaped double quotes:

Regex: `".+?(?<!\\)"`

Code:

```
var txt1 = "\"This is \\\"some text\\\" to capture\" \"no other text\"";
var regex1 = new Regex(@""".+?(?<!\\)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase  | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
var c1 = regex1.Matches(txt1).Cast<Match>().Select(d => d.Value.Trim()).ToList();
```

Output:

```
"This is \"some text\" to capture"
"no other text"
```

Answer (score 2):

As eckes said in his comment, try using

> "[^"]*"

This should match a quote, then any number of characters that aren't quotes, then another quote.  The other answers will not match a 0-length, depending on if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = @"""@test"" skip ""2 3"" skip ""TEST"" skip ""te st"" skip ""@#""";
var values = Regex.Matches(input, @"\""(.+?)\""")
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: I think, same stalker again... http://stackoverflow.com/a/29242340/2345956 Anthing to say about the answer?