# find specific nodes in Microsoft REST XML response

Tags: c#, xml

i tried to find the the value in the node TravelDistance,as it show in the picture
but i also get Null 
this is my try

```
string url = @"https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes?wp.0=43.104234, -77.627686&wp.1=43.103219, -77.621267&wp.2=43.100619, -77.624963&output=xml&distanceUnit=Mile&key= Ap5gFiZ56mvoqUXoswD2Hw81EZk5xMaCcP6JNzJOc-0xAf2wqTYgvSUZ8uhXJifZ";
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(url);

            XmlNode nodea = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Response/ResourceSets/ResourceSet/Resources/Route/TravelDistance");
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");
var dist = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//x:Route/x:TravelDistance", mgr).InnerText;
```

Comment: Why this answer has value "-1"? This is not  justly

Comment: @FoggyFinder Because an idiot voted before testing or trying to understand it.

Comment: good job !  i don't know who give you -1 i test your code is correct. but could you explain it.

Comment: @HusseinTalib  Just you need to read something about xml namespaces (See the first line of your xml).

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by this way

```
string url = @"https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes?wp.0=43.104234, -77.627686&wp.1=43.103219, -77.621267&wp.2=43.100619, -77.624963&output=xml&distanceUnit=Mile&key= Ap5gFiZ56mvoqUXoswD2Hw81EZk5xMaCcP6JNzJOc-0xAf2wqTYgvSUZ8uhXJifZ";

            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url)
                                  as HttpWebRequest;
            string result = null;
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()  as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader =
                    new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
              string TravelDistance = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<TravelDistance>") + "<TravelDistance>".Length, (result.IndexOf("</TravelDistance>") - result.IndexOf("<TravelDistance>")) - "<TravelDistance>".Length);
```

if any one have addition solution tell as please